# local and global scope coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

With javascript:

```
function myFunc() {
    var x = 5;
};

console.log(x);
```

I get `//undefined` and with:

```
function myFunc() {
        x = 5;
    };

    console.log(x);
```

I get `5`

With `coffeescript` this variable `var x = 5;` is `x = 5`.

For example this is possible?:

```
myFunc ->
  window.x = 5;

    console.log window.x
```

Instead of:

```
myFunc ->
 x = 5;

 console.log x
```

My question is **How I can differentiate a global variable of a local variable with CoffeeScript?**

Comment: The answer is really that you're not *supposed* to use global variables

Answer (score 1):

for global scope you should use functions like this:

```
myFunc = =>
  @x = 5;

myFunc()

console.log x
```

example of generated code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Upward/wZ7w4/